# Problems importing OpenCV in Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, opencv, command-line, pycharm

I was trying to learn how to use OpenCV in python and I'm trying to use PyCharm for that purpose (I'm new to this IDE). My problems start right from the beginning since I find myself unable to import cv2. 
Using Python 3.8.0 in Windows.

I've seen at other solutions on this website where using the GUI or writing the following line: "pip install opencv-python" into the console. The results are shown below:

[image: Result from using PyCharm's console log]

[image: Result from using the GUI]

Nonetheless, from the command line in Windows, if I install "opencv-python" with pip as before, I get no problems and it allowed me to import it.

[image: Result from using Windows Command Line]

I thought it had to do with me installing it in 'C:/Users/myname/' so I uninstalled it with pip and went ahead and tried to repeat the same steps as before and got the same results.

So I went ahead and got in a loop where I installed OpenCV with the Windows Command Line, uninstalled it, tried to import it in PyCharm, repeat. And at the end, I just tried a bunch of solutions from which none of them work.

I must say that one of the things I tried was to create other projects and one of them worked out just fine, just after uninstalling OpenCV with Command-Line. But in the other project, it just didn't work out.

Comment: Make sure that PyCharm is using the same python as your command line. Are there multiple versions of python installed on your system? Are you using Virtual environments?

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem when starting opencv, I recommend you to use "Conda environment", for this solution you should install [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) and then follow this instruction: [virtual environments for Python with conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#:%7E:text=Configuring%20a%20conda%20environment%20in%20PyCharm,-In%20the%20Settings&text=Select%20Preferences.,dialog%20box%2C%20select%20Conda%20Environment.)